# Scripting the creation of a file on multiple drives using foreach

Tags: powershell, new-item

I'm trying to script the automation of creating a file called no_sms_on_drive.sms on all my drives that do not contain sccm, in this case j:. When it starts the Foreach loop I can get the $dltr variable set, but I get an error stating that -Path has a null value.

```
##Define no_sms_on_drive.sms on all drives except j:\
### Get all the logical disks with drivetype 3 which is a hard drives
$disks = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DriveType='3'"
### Filter out j:\ which contains SCCM 
$NonSMSDrives = $disks | ? { $_.DeviceID -notmatch "[j]:"}
### Create the no sms file on each of the drives
$MakeNonSMSDrives = ForEach($d in $NonSMSDrives){ $dltr = $_.DeviceID | New-Item -Path $dltr -Name "no_sms_on_drive.sms" -ItemType "File" }
```

Comment: It should be `$dltr = $d.DeviceID` instead of `$dltr = $_.DeviceID` and you should replace the pipe inside your scriptblock with a semicolon or line break. And you should not use `Get-WmiObject` anymore since it is deprecated. Use `Get-CimInstance` instead.

Comment: Suggest making that the answer rather than a comment - comments don't help other people looking for solutions and you can't mark the answer as correct (thereby leaving lots of "unanswered" questions). Comments on the question should really be about seeking clarification, like "have you tried X?" or "this makes no sense as written".

Comment: @LeeM ... 'see ... seems like it's been not urgent at all. No responce at all. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Yeah, half the time I get zero response on good answers, even when others have upvoted them and/or it's the only proposed answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-WmiObject` is deprecated. Instead you should use `Get-CimInstance`. Since you don't need the variables later on I'd suggest to do it without them.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDisk |
    Where-Object {
        $_.DriveType -eq 3 -and
        $_.DeviceID -notmatch 'j'
    } |
        ForEach-Object {
            $Path = Join-Path -Path $_.DeviceID -ChildPath 'no_sms_on_drive.sms'
            New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType 'File' -WhatIf
        }
```

If you're satisfied with the output you can remove the `-WhatIf` parameter to actually create the desired files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using the following

```
$NonSMSDrives = "Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | ? { $_.Name -notlike [jdX]} | Select -ExpandProperty Root"

$MakeNonSMSDrives = "ForEach( $d in $NonSMSDrives){ New-Item -Path $d -Name 'no_sms_on_drive.sms' -ItemType 'File' }"
```

Comment: So did you even try Olaf's solution? Since that would have worked. Anyway, since you're using a slightly different method to identify the drive, you might as well accept your own answer, so no-one else wastes their time looking at it.